# How can I send data with two-way-binding from HTML to $rootScope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, two-way-binding

I know little about angularjs , I really like two-way-binding in it . I knew how to send data from HTML to controller with ng-model . Now my problem is I code a function in app.js like this

```
 .run(function ($rootScope) {
        console.log($rootScope.test)
 }
```

and this is my HTML

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="test" 
      ng-change="vali_repassword()" ng-required="more">
```

I want to get `test` in ng-model , how to achieve this?

Comment: Where are you setting this `$rootScope.test` value and is this html is one of your controllers' template?

Comment: I think it's the same as using $scope , so I didn't set $rootScope.test's value . About controller , I put it in .run ... Sorry for my limited level ~

Comment: `$scope.test` will return you the value of that from your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller associated to your HTML, inject the `$rootScope` and the `$scope` and bind the `$rootScope` value inside the `$scope` so that you can use that variable inside the associated HTML.

FYI, usage of `$rootScope` for sharing data is a bad practice. There are a lot of ways for doing it instead. For example, use services instead.

```
.controller(function ($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.test = $rootScope.test;
}

<input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="test" 
      ng-change="vali_repassword()" ng-required="more">
```

Then `onChange` (`vali_repassword`) you need to assign back the value to the `$rootScope.test` to be sure the value is updated in the `$rootScope` too.

Comment: Thank you so mush for you assistance , and now I think the mistake I made was I didn't understand the role of controller .